# Post request successful but Dio throwing DioError code 500 and returning content-type: text/html;

Tags: flutter, dart, http, https, dio

I'm new to Dio. I'm trying to call an Api to create a new user and when I call this function `createUser()`, the user is created in the backend but Dio throws DioError: status code 500.
This is the function:

```dart
Future<User> createUser({
  required String email,
  required String username,
  required String password,
  required String password2,
}) async {
  BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
    baseUrl: 'https://XXXXXX.XXXX.com',
  );
  final Dio dio = Dio(options);

  Response? response;
  try {
    response = await dio.post(
      '/signup_person',
      data: {
        'email': email,
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'password2': password2
      },
    );
    print('Request completed');
  } on DioError catch (e) {
    if (e.response != null) { // This is the block that gets executed
      print('kmfovrnf');
      print(e.response!.data);
      print('=====');
      print(e.error);
      print('=====');
      print(e.response!.headers);
      print('=====');
      print(e.response!.requestOptions);
    } else {
      print('vinro');
      // Something happened in setting up or sending the request that triggered an Error
      print(e.requestOptions);
      print(e.message);
    }
    rethrow;
  } catch (e) {
    print('Network Helper catching error: $e');
    throw Exception(e);
  }

  print('Here');
  if (response.statusCode == 201) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> responseMap = response.data;

    print('Here22');
    return User.fromJson(responseMap);
  } else {
    print('Response : ${response.data}');
    throw Exception(response.data.toString());
  }
}
```

The terminal logs:

```
Performing hot restart...
Restarted application in 6,075ms.
I/flutter (28797): kmfovrnf
I/flutter (28797): <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter (28797): <html lang="en">
I/flutter (28797): <head>
I/flutter (28797):   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
I/flutter (28797):   <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
I/flutter (28797):   <title>DoesNotExist
I/flutter (28797):           at /signup_person</title>
I/flutter (28797):   <style type="text/css">
I/flutter (28797):     html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
I/flutter (28797):     body * { padding:10px 20px; }
I/flutter (28797):     body * * { padding:0; }
I/flutter (28797):     body { font:small sans-serif; background-color:#fff; color:#000; }
I/flutter (28797):     body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
I/flutter (28797):     h1 { font-weight:normal; }
I/flutter (28797):     h2 { margin-bottom:.8em; }
I/flutter (28797):     h3 { margin:1em 0 .5em 0; }
I/flutter (28797):     h4 { margin:0 0 .5em 0; font-weight: normal; }
I/flutter (28797):     code, pre { font-size: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word; }
I/flutter (28797):     summary { cursor: pointer; }
I/flutter (28797):     table { border:1px solid #ccc; border-collapse: collapse; width:100%; background:white; }
I/flutter (28797):     tbody td, tbody th { vertical-align:top; padding:2px 3px; }
I/flutter (28797):     thead th {
I/flutter (28797):       padding:1px 6px 1px 3px; background:#fefefe; text-align:left;
I/flutter (28797):       font-weight:normal; font-size:11px; border:1px solid #ddd;
I/flutter (28797): =====
I/flutter (28797): Http status error [500]
I/flutter (28797): =====
I/flutter (28797): keep-alive: timeout=5, max=100
I/flutter (28797): date: Wed, 04 Jan 2023 09:05:45 GMT
I/flutter (28797): transfer-encoding: chunked
I/flutter (28797): vary: Accept-Encoding
I/flutter (28797): content-encoding: gzip
I/flutter (28797): referrer-policy: same-origin
I/flutter (28797): content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
I/flutter (28797): x-frame-options: DENY
I/flutter (28797): cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin
I/flutter (28797): x-content-type-options: nosniff
I/flutter (28797): x-turbo-charged-by: LiteSpeed
I/flutter (28797): server: LiteSpeed
I/flutter (28797): =====
I/flutter (28797): Instance of 'RequestOptions'
E/flutter (28797): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Error occurred
E/flutter (28797): #0      makeRequest (package:reprex/main.dart:84:7)
E/flutter (28797): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (28797): #1      MyApp.build.<anonymous closure> (package:reprex/main.dart:25:21)
E/flutter (28797): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (28797):
```

The function is to create a user, the user is created. When I test it with Postman, the response code is 201.
Please, help.

This is the postman request

[image: postman request screenshot]

**Edit:**

I tried switching to http but I'm getting the same error. Here's the code:

```dart
Uri url = Uri.https('XXXXXXX.XXXXX.com', '/signup_person');
var response = await http.post(
  url,
  body: {
    'email': email,
    'username': username,
    'password': password,
    'password2': password2
  },
);
print('=====================');
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('=====================');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');
print('=====================');
print('Response request: ${response.request}');
print('=====================');

print('Request completed');
```

Here's the terminal logs:

```
I/flutter (30166): Response status: 500
I/flutter (30166): =====================
I/flutter (30166): Response body: <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter (30166): <html lang="en">
I/flutter (30166): <head>
I/flutter (30166):   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
I/flutter (30166):   <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
I/flutter (30166):   <title>SMTPRecipientsRefused
I/flutter (30166):           at /signup_person</title>
I/flutter (30166):   <style type="text/css">
I/flutter (30166):     html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
I/flutter (30166):     body * { padding:10px 20px; }
I/flutter (30166):     body * * { padding:0; }
I/flutter (30166):     body { font:small sans-serif; background-color:#fff; color:#000; }
I/flutter (30166):     body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
I/flutter (30166):     h1 { font-weight:normal; }
I/flutter (30166):     h2 { margin-bottom:.8em; }
I/flutter (30166):     h3 { margin:1em 0 .5em 0; }
I/flutter (30166):     h4 { margin:0 0 .5em 0; font-weight: normal; }
I/flutter (30166):     code, pre { font-size: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word; }
I/flutter (30166):     summary { cursor: pointer; }
I/flutter (30166):     table { border:1px solid #ccc; border-collapse: collapse; width:100%; background:white; }
I/flutter (30166):     tbody td, tbody th { vertical-align:top; padding:2px 3px; }
I/flutter (30166):     thead th {
I/flutter (30166):       padding:1px 6px 1px 3px; background:#fefefe; text-align:left;
I/flutter (30166):       font-weight:normal; font-size:11px
I/flutter (30166): =====================
I/flutter (30166): Response request: POST https://XXXXXX.XXX/signup_person
I/flutter (30166): =====================
I/flutter (30166): Request completed
```

Comment: share the postman request screenshot. That will help.

Comment: you can recheck the headers and contact with your backend dev

Comment: Try with package `http`. In `await dio.post`, replace dio with http, replace the first parameter with Uri.parse('the full url') and replace the named parameter `data` with `body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was getting status code 500 because I was testing the API with jargons emails like "wvmds@apq.cdff". The backend throws code 500 but still creates the user. So when I test it the second time with the same jargon, it returns a normal response with message 'User exists'.

Thank you for the help. I'm on my way to fight the backend dev now.